# Can you save and use customer parameters when saving a catboost model with onnx?

Tags: catboost, onnx, onnxruntime, catboostregressor

I have a Catboost regression model that I'm saving with onnx to use elsewhere, all using Python. Is it possible to save custom parameters in the onnx model and extract them with onnx runtime? I'd like to save metadata around the model.

Answer (score 2):

Please see https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/onnx/onnx.proto#L249. You can use this field to store any metadata about the model. This is a free-form data field; hence onnxruntime (ORT) doesn't know anything about it. What do you want ORT to extract and why? Also as a side note, you'll get faster responses if you use https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxruntime/issues. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @pranavsharma. I'm making anomaly detection models and I want to store reconstruction error thresholds with the models, for use during run time.